# Docker image build issue in Eclipse

Tags: docker, microservices, spotify, spring-boot-maven-plugin, docker-toolbox

I am trying to build Docker image of Spring Boot microservice project using Spotify but getting below error:

> [ERROR] ADD failed: stat
> /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder873622989/target/Micro-Eureka-Server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:
> no such file or directory

I don't understand why it is appending ***stat/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder873622989/*** while building the image. Below is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk
MAINTAINER Nishant Varshney <nvarshney44@gmail.com>
RUN echo 'This is OK1'
ADD /target/Micro-Eureka-Server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Micro-Eureka-Server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN echo 'This is OK2'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/Micro-Eureka-Server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 8761
```

I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 and trying to build image using Eclipse.